# How to allow users to make their profiles private or public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, user-defined-functions

I have a Rails 3 app and this is something I'm trying to figure out.

I already have an app that users have to log in to use but their profiles are viewable by the public. The URL of their profile is http://myapp.com/users/username

I want to add a feature in their settings where they can set their profiles either public or private. It is already public since everyone can see it, but how do I allow the private feature?

Basically, I just want this part (http://myapp.com/users/username) to be able to set to private or public by the user.

Comment: So do you want some sort of 'My Account' page that contains their information?

Comment: What do you mean by "private"? What—specifically—should happen when someone attempts to access a private page? Nicely-formatted error page? HTTP 404? 403? 401? In general, save a variable in the database, and when someone attempts to access the URL, check the DB and send the appropriate response.

Comment: No, they already have profiles that show their posts in the link http://myapp.com/users/username. Everyone can view it even when not logged in, so I would like to allow the users an option to set their profile to private. When it is set to private and when someone attempts to access it, it will show say ("You are not logged in. Please sign in here.")

Comment: Then in controller of your profile add smth like `redirect_to :action => "show" unless currect_user.logged?`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but how can I allow users to have the option? Some may want their profile to be public, while some may want them private

Comment: As @Phrogz already suggested, you are to extend the `User` table with boolean `public_profile` field.

Comment: Ok, so to confirm, I will add a new boolean field called public_profile in the User table, with the :default => true. Then I can use this code <% if public_profile=>true? %> <% else %> in the view show.html.erb. Did I forget anything?

Comment: @johbones Generally it's better to redirect or use a different view rather than switch the page completely in the view based on a variable.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm fairly new to RoR so does this make sense? I will create a new boolean field in the User table then do a redirect with this "redirect_to :action => "show" unless public_profile.true?"

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column for a public/private boolean:

```
rails g migration AddIs_publicToUsers is_public:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

In your view/users/show.html.erb (or wherever your user page is) add:

```
<% if current_user.is_public %>
  *Paste in display html/erb for your user show page.
<% else %>
  Sorry. Is Private Profile. 
<% end %>
```

You will also have to make the attribute accessible, in models/user.rb for rails 3 and below, or in controller/users_controller.rb for rails 4.

Rails 3:

```
attr_accessible :is_public
```

Rails 4:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:is_public)
end
```